# Apache Ignite Fault Tolerance

Tags: ignite

I have few questions about Ignite Cache in Partitioned mode

1)When a node goes down in a Ignite cluster, If the failed node is primary for a key, does the backup of this become new primary?.

2)What happens to the backup copies in the failed node? will they be recreated in the cluster?.

3)If I set CacheRebalanceMode in cache configuration will it be applicable for node failure as well or only in case of node addition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes, this is right. Former backup will become a new primary and new backup will receive the copy in background.
2. Yes, if backup is lost, new node will assigned for this role. It will receive the copy in background.
3. In synchronous rebalance mode a node will not complete start process and user will not be able to use the API until the data is rebalanced. This doesn't affect the rebalancing process in case of failures.

Comment: Thanks Valentin, If my understnading is correct , the cacheRebalanceMode is only applicable for node addition and not failure?.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Sync rebalancing means that you can't use the API on the joining node until the rebalancing is completed.